# updating the outer scope object in side self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, closures, self-invoking-function

Can any one help me understand what mistake i am doing?
Or help me to give an alternate solution for the same?

http://jsfiddle.net/mrrajesh1982/eynpu8rj/2/

```
  function isValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    $('<img>', {
        src: url,
        load: function() {
            callback(true);
        },
        error: function() {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}
var ndata = [{imgUrl: "https://library.barnard.edu/sites/default/files/paired_t_test_output_1_and_2.png"},{imgUrl: "url1"},{imgUrl: "http://statistics-help-for-students.com/How_do_I_report_paired_samples_T_test_data_in_APA_style_files/image002.jpg"}];


for (var i = 0; i < ndata.length; i++){
    var imageUrl = ndata[i].imgUrl;
    (function(pictureUrl){
        isValidImageUrl(pictureUrl, function(result) {
            if (!result) {
                ndata[i].imgUrl = "http://media.tcc.fl.edu/webcourses/ctll/Developing_Your_Teaching_Philosophy/examples.jpg";
                //I am getting error on this line as TypeError: ndata[i] is undefined

                //My question here is to how to update the ndata array obejct with valid image URL? 
            }
        });
    }(imageUrl));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(ndata));// Expecting ndata[1].imgUrl should get updated inside self invoking function with valid image url
```

Comment: `i` is wrong, and you're logging before the object has updated.

Comment: @ Scimonster , As I have made self-invoking function, I am expecting it should work fine. Is it possible for you to make this work? I will be regretful for your help. I understand call back logic, but not sure how to use this for in for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
  function isValidImageUrl(url, callback) {
    $('<img>', {
        src: url,
        load: function() {
            callback(true);
        },
        error: function() {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}
var ndata = [{imgUrl: "https://library.barnard.edu/sites/default/files/paired_t_test_output_1_and_2.png"},{imgUrl: "url1"},{imgUrl: "http://statistics-help-for-students.com/How_do_I_report_paired_samples_T_test_data_in_APA_style_files/image002.jpg"}];


for (var i = 0; i < ndata.length; i++){
    var imageUrl = ndata[i].imgUrl;
    (function(pictureUrl, i){
        isValidImageUrl(pictureUrl, function(result) {
            if (!result) {
                ndata[i].imgUrl = "http://media.tcc.fl.edu/webcourses/ctll/Developing_Your_Teaching_Philosophy/examples.jpg";
                //I am getting error on this line as TypeError: ndata[i] is undefined

                //My question here is to how to update the ndata array obejct with valid image URL? 

            console.log(ndata);
            }
        });
    }(imageUrl, i));
}
```

In addition to passing `imageUrl`, you also need to pass `i` to your anonymous function, because otherwise it's already lost its value when the callback runs.

Another thing, you are running the `console.log()` before the callback has run. You need to log from within the callback. Also note that there's no guarantee that it will return in order.

Comment: Thanks @Scimonster for quick reply. My use case is little different, I get the JSON object array(ndata) from ajax call as a response. Once reponse received I need to  validate each object and update image url if necessary. then pass the updated response to UI though Underscore client side template. This is why I wanted to updated ndata out side of for loop. Please help me how to make this possible?